# Rdlc Reports (Reportviewer) - Asp.net Web Forms/ MVC

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, report, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

**How can I show an HTML page in a cell or can it happen?**

Thank yoou

Answer (score 0):

Go to Placeholder properties, at Markup type choose HTML.

[image]

But make sure that, the dataset contains HTML tag.